# Cannot use root ssh despite option "PermitRootLogin yes" in sshd_config

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I am unable to connect to ssh despite the fact that `PermitRootLogin` option is set to "yes" in my sshd_config.

```
ssh localhost
root@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Here is my full `sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PermitRootLogin yes
AllowUsers otheruser
```

**What prevent the ssh connection as root and how to fix it?**

Comment: Note: Password authentication, and allow root, are both asking to be hacked. If this machine is visible on the internet, then don't do it. Use a public/private key, and use sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AllowUsers
>
> If specified, login is allowed only for user named that match one of the patterns.

Add root to the list:

```
AllowUsers root otheruser
```